# bash script multiple if condition not executing/working

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am trying to write the input based bash script which will trigger the respective app build script. And if the input is "all" then all apps will get called.
I am facing issue here, if entered as "all" then only app_1 and app_2 are getting called. what could be the issue,

```
if [ "${_BUILD_MODE}" = "all" ] || [ "${_BUILD_MODE}" = "app_1" ]
then 
   echo "BUILD_STAGE APP_1 build started"
fi
if [ "${_BUILD_MODE}" = "all" ] || [ "${_BUILD_MODE}" = "app_2" ]
then 
   echo "BUILD_STAGE APP_2 build started"
fi
if [ "${_BUILD_MODE}" = "all" ] || [ "${_BUILD_MODE}" = "app_3" ]
then 
   echo "BUILD_STAGE APP_3 build started"
fi
if [ "${_BUILD_MODE}" = "all" ] || [ "${_BUILD_MODE}" = "app_4" ]
then 
   echo "BUILD_STAGE APP_4 build started"
fi
if [ "${_BUILD_MODE}" = "all" ] || [ "${_BUILD_MODE}" = "app_5" ]
then 
   echo "BUILD_STAGE APP_5 build started"
fi
if [ "${_BUILD_MODE}" = "all" ] || [ "${_BUILD_MODE}" = "app_6" ]
then 
   echo "BUILD_STAGE APP_6 build started"
fi
```

Comment: Add a line showing how you assign `_BUILD_MODE`.  I say that because I just pasted your commands into a script, and they worked perfectly.

Comment: So maybe add the entire script for analysis... please don't answer in comments, but [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/741984/edit) your question instead to keep it up-to-date and relevant info available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really about what you're asking, but that sort of if-chains look awkward as you're repeating some pieces of code there, even if it's just the `[ "${_BUILD_MODE}" = "all" ]` here.

Instead, I'd put the tasks into e.g. functions and make an array with their names (untested):

```
app_1() {
    echo "BUILD_STAGE APP_1 build... "
}
app_2() {
    echo "BUILD_STAGE APP_2 build... "
}
tasks=(app_1 app_2)

for task in "${tasks[@]}"; do 
    if [ "${_BUILD_MODE}" = "all" ] || [ "${_BUILD_MODE}" = "$task" ]; then
        "$task"
    fi
done
```

Note that the function names must be identical to the task names as used in `_BUILD_MODE` here.

Here, if you need to do changes to how the tasks run, e.g. by wrapping them in a subshell like [Stéphane suggests](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/741989/170373), or add some printout to separate them, you can do it one place in the loop.

Answer (score 3):

That does not happen with the sample code you're giving here. Presumably those `echo`s are just place holders for more complicated tasks you're performing, my guess would be that the task for `app_2` actually changes the  value of `$_BUILD_MODE`.

Here, you could do:

```
case $_BUILD_MODE in
  (all | app_1) task for app_1 ;;&
  (all | app_2) task for app_2 ;;&
  (all | app_3) task for app_3 ;;&
  ...
esac
```

Which would make it shorter, neater and also avoid that particular issue as `$_BUILD_MODE` is dereferenced only once at the beginning.

`;;&` above is bash-specific. In zsh and mksh, the equivalent syntax is with `;|`. zsh, mksh and bash support `;;` (from the Bourne shell and the only standard one) and `;&`  (from the Korn shell).

It's also possible that the task for `app_2` calls `exit` or `exec some-other-command` or runs into  a fatal error or has the shell process killed¹. A work around for that would be to perform the tasks in subshells by wrapping them inside `(...)`.

Try running the script with `bash -o xtrace` (same as `bash -x`) to see what happens.

---

<sup>¹  for instance by a SIGPIPE if a builtin writes to a broken pipe or by SIGXCPU if it exceeds some resource limit...</sup>